# Retrieve token using msal

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I have used MSAL for angular to generate jwt from AzureAd.
I need to retrieve this token and send it to signalr connection request for authentication.
I don't see an API in MSAL service to get the token back.
Any thoughts??

Answer (score -1):

You can get the tokens by either having your custom msalinterceptor, or you can just call the acquiretoken apis
as per the documentation here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular#3-get-tokens-for-web-api-calls

You can subscribe to the callback and do something with the returned token,

or if you want to directly call get the tokens: https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/msal-angular/
can run something like acquiretokensilent(),

Comment: I need it to pass to signalr connection so interpreter won't work. The callback is one option but Is there an api on msal service which can get it to me? I tried to read the local storage, but the token stored in local storage is not exactly the same. it is modified.

Comment: Answer doesn't answer the question ?